# Is testing of Android XML layouts with TDD a good idea?

Tags: android, xml, tdd

The Scala and Java code used in the Android Application has been created according TDD.

Is testing of XML part of Android TDD Policy? If positive, for which of the following code should a Test created first before writing the code to meet the demands of the Android TDD Policy?

**/HelloWorld/res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="app_name">HelloWorld</string>
<string name="hello_utrecht">Hello Utrecht!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

**/HelloWorld/res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_utrecht" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say no.  TDD is a great approach for developing code, but even its most hardcore supporters admit that TDD is not a great fit 100% of the time.  It is great for algorithmic code.  It tends to not be beneficial in UI development.

TDD says that you must write a failing test first.  So how would you write a test for a layout? It can be done for sure.  There are testing tools (e.g. Robotium) that can validate UIs.  However these tests are often time consuming to write, and to execute.  Plus they require your application to be functional enough that the tool can navigate the UI to the screen of interest.  All of these issues directly negate one of the biggest gains of TDD - simple, fast validation of your code.

This is not to say that UIs are not to be tested.  Functional tests with tools like Robotium are invaluable for future regression tests of the UI.  I am simply saying the TDD & Unit tests are not a good match for UI code - in general that is.

Comment: For TDD you are writing tests against behavioral specification's (acceptance tests). A layout alone doesn't have a behavior. [EJK | http://stackoverflow.com/users/1072150/ejk] get's it right when he talks about validation.